# What is the function of PMLIBPARENTDIRS in ExtUtils::MakeMaker?

Tags: perl, build, makemaker

One of our projects has an ancient, inherited `Makefile.PL` based on [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.02/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm) which contains the following:

```
WriteMakefile(
    #  ... Many lines omitted ...
    PMLIBDIRS      => [ 'lib', '$(BASEEXT)' ],
    PMLIBPARENTDIRS => [ 'lib' ],
);
```

The `PMLIBDIRS` option is clearly explained in the documentation (linked above), but `PMLIBPARENTDIRS` is not documented that I can find. It is mentioned twice in the [source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.02/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm) however, but not in what appears to be any functional way (i.e. in configuration and documentation).

Commenting out the `PMLIBPARENTDIRS` option does not have any immediately obvious negative impact when building the package.

What does this parameter do? Or is it obsolete?